# Build a list with a bash script

Tags: bash, yaml

I'm kind of new to bash scripting and I'm looking for an answer that explains the thought process when developing a script.

I have a list of hosts in a config file but need to convert it to YAML.   I need to remove the hostname and IP from the config  and generate a new config for it.

So how to identify and remove that first set of info,  then  insert it to a new set.

```
<Host "HOSTNAME">
  Address "10.10.10.10"
  Version 2
  Community "STRINGHERE"
  Collect "linux_cpu_wait_raw" "linux_cpu_nice_raw" "linux_cpu_kernel_raw" "linux_mem_total" "linux_mem_avail" "linux_load"
</Host>
```

Should look like this

```
'HOSTNAME':
    Address: '10.10.10.10'
    Version: 2
    Community: 'STRINGHERE'
    Collect: ['linux_cpu_wait_raw', 'linux_cpu_nice_raw', 'linux_cpu_kernel_raw', 'linux_mem_total', 'linux_mem_avail', 'linux_load']
```

I am having a hard time finding an example to do something like what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks,

I appreciate any direction.

Comment: Use sed or awk. What have you tried, and why is that not working for you?

Comment: As CodeGnome indicates you are generally expected to attempt to solve your own problems before asking for help here. In addition to `awk` (which would work if your input is guaranteed to be regular) you should probably look into `jq` and/or `xmlstarlet` (as well as other languages that can consume xml) to be able to do this robustly.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!.

If you don't have specialized tools you can hack a script like this

```
$ awk -v q="'" '{gsub(/"/,q)} 
   NF==2&&/Host/{sub(">",":"); print $2; next} 
            NF>2{printf "\t%s: [" , $1; 
                 for(i=2;i<NF;i++) printf "%s, ", $i; 
                 printf "%s]\n", $NF} 
           NF==2{printf "\t%s: %s\n", $1, $2}' xml

'HOSTNAME':
        Address: '10.10.10.10'
        Version: 2
        Community: 'STRINGHERE'
        Collect: ['linux_cpu_wait_raw', 'linux_cpu_nice_raw', 'linux_cpu_kernel_raw', 'linux_mem_total', 'linux_mem_avail', 'linux_load']
```

but this has no knowledge of the structure and may fail if your input format changes...

**Explanation**

> `-v q="'"` set a variable for single quotes, since `awk` script is in
>   single quotes, it requires escaping and too much visual noise, that's
>   how I prefer to use it.
>
> `{gsub(/"/,q)}` replace all double quotes with single quotes
>
> `NF==2&&/Host/{sub(">",":"); print $2; next}` for the line with two
>   fields (default field separator is white space) and matching pattern
>   Host replace `>` sign with `:` and print the second field and move to
>   the next line
>
> `NF>2{printf "\t%s: [" ...` for lines more than two
>   fields print the fields in the square bracket form
>
> `NF==2{printf ...` for other lines with two fields only, print in the
>   `name: value` form

Comment: This worked well,  Can you break it down or show me where I can read up to take it apart?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation with `sed`.

```
#removed closed tag
\#</.*#d
#removed open tag
s/<[a-zA-Z]\+ //
#append colon to open tag line
s/>/:/
#append colon to other lines
s/^\(.*[a-zA-Z]\+\)\(\s.*\)$/\1:\2/
#quote with brackets
s/\("[^"]\+"\($\|\s\)\)\{2,\}/\[&\]/
#replace double quote with single quote
s/"/'/g
#add comma seperated
s/'\s/', /g
```

Save the sed syntax above as `file.sed`, and run as

```
$ sed -f file.sed file.txt
```

Or with a single line command

```
$ sed -e '\#</.*#d' -e 's/<[a-zA-Z]\+ //' -e 's/>/:/' -e 's/^\(.*[a-zA-Z]\+\)\(\s.*\)$/\1:\2/' -e 's/\("[^"]\+"\($\|\s\)\)\{2,\}/\[&\]/' -e "s/\"/'/g" -e "s/'\\s/', /g" file.txt
```

If your file format changed, it might not work. An example output is

```
$ sed -f file.sed file.txt 
'HOSTNAME':
  Address: '10.10.10.10'
  Version: 2
  Community: 'STRINGHERE'
  Collect: ['linux_cpu_wait_raw', 'linux_cpu_nice_raw', 'linux_cpu_kernel_raw', 'linux_mem_total', 'linux_mem_avail', 'linux_load']
```